# colorization of Quickfix results in Vim

Tags: vim, cygwin, quickfixj

How can I have the results in quickfix colorized when I use `grep` in Vim?

I have tried:

`set grepprg=grep\ --color=always\ -n\ $*\ /dev/null`

but it's not working.

I am using Vim 7.4 on cygwin and I have also tried it in Linux Mint 15. Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With `--color=always`, you instruct grep to always output *ANSI color sequences* (stuff that looks like `^[[32;40m`), even though the output is not to a terminal.

Unfortunately, Vim does not understand these sequences; it has its own (regular expression-based) *syntax highlighting*.

Though the [AnsiEsc.vim](http://vim.sourceforge.net/script.php?script_id=302) plugin can translate the former into the latter, I don't think this is helpful here. (I've briefly tried it, and it didn't work as expected).

#### solution

You could write a custom `:Grep` command that feeds the passed arguments to `:grep`, and then defines the appropriate syntax highlighting for the quickfix window. A problem is that the regular expression dialects of `grep` and Vim are different. You can avoid that problem by using `:vimgrep`.

In fact, the simplest solution is to first search for the *pattern* inside Vim:

```
/pattern
```

and then follow up with the actual grep:

```
:vimgrep // file1 file2
```

With `:set hlsearch`, you'll then have the matches automatically highlighted (in all windows, including the quickfix window, though only for as long as you don't search for something else).

Comment: Even when I use :vimgrep and :set hlsearch I still don't get my results in the quickfix window colorized, am I missing something? thanks.

Comment: An alternative to `/pattern` that won't clobber your search register is `:match Search /pattern/`